# How can I sort ruby hash with string key by setting priority to the key elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a hash with the following values:

```
hash = {
  'red': { something: ''},
  'green': { something: '' },
  'yellow': { something: ''}
}
```

What is the simplest way to do something like this:

```
hash.sort_by_key_with_priority(['green', 'yellow', 'red'])
```

And return:

```
hash = {
  'green': { something: '' },
  'yellow': { something: ''},
  'red': { something: ''},
}
```

Comment: Those are not string keys, btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your priority array contains all of the hash keys, you don't need sorting. You can simply take the hash apart and construct a new one.

```
hash = {
  red: { something: ''},
  green: { something: '' },
  yellow: { something: ''}
}

priority = %i[green yellow red]

hash.slice(*priority)
# => {:green=>{:something=>""}, :yellow=>{:something=>""}, :red=>{:something=>""}}
```

Comment: This is a clean solution. +1

Comment: for compatibility purposes. Prior to ruby 2.5.0 (`Hash#slice`) you could use `priority.zip(hash.values_at(*priority)).to_h` or even older (ruby < 2.1) `Hash[priority.zip(hash.values_at(*priority))]`

Comment: @engineersmnky: this is tagged with [ruby-on-rails]. I think activesupport had Hash#slice for ages.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you are correct back to 3.0.0 (although the implementation leaves a bit to be desired IMO) and while tagged rails nothing in this question appears to be rails specific

Comment: How reliable is this method for sorting?

Comment: @fatfrog: exactly the same as relying on order of key-value pairs in a hashmap in the first place. It's an unordered data structure, in theory. But ruby's implementation (at least MRI, not sure about others) maintains insertion order for keys.

Answer (score 5):

If there are keys in the hash not included in priority array:

```
>> h = {red: 512, green: 63, yellow: 99, foo: 42, baz: 'hi'}
=> {:red=>512, :green=>63, :yellow=>99, :foo=>42, :baz=>"hi"}
>> p = %i[green yellow red]
=> [:green, :yellow, :red]

# this puts keys not in array at start
# h.sort_by { |k, v| p.include?(k) ? p.index(k) : -1 }
>> h.sort_by { |k, v| p.index(k) || -1 }
=> [[:foo, 42], [:baz, "hi"], [:green, 63], [:yellow, 99], [:red, 512]]

# this puts keys not in array at end
# h.sort_by { |k, v| p.include?(k) ? p.index(k) : p.size }
>> h.sort_by { |k, v| p.index(k) || p.size }
=> [[:green, 63], [:yellow, 99], [:red, 512], [:foo, 42], [:baz, "hi"]]
```

Use `to_h` method on result to convert to `hash`

Comment: You could also use the methods provided above e.g. `Hash#slice` in combination with `Hash#merge` like `h.slice(*p).merge(h) {|_,o,_| o}`. Also `Array#index` returns nil if the element does not exist so `p.index(k) || -1` removes the need for the ternary and the need to traverse the `Array` twice

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks a lot, `p.index(k) || -1` is good to know, I've been using ternary like this in elsewhere too.. need to understand `slice+merge` though, also I feel that could be added to accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {
    'red': { something: ''},
    'green': { something: '' },
    'yellow': { something: ''}
}
```

Code

```
p ['green', 'yellow', 'red'].map{|value|[value.to_sym,hash[value.to_sym]]}.to_h
```

output

```
{:green=>{:something=>""}, :yellow=>{:something=>""}, :red=>{:something=>""}}
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you very much. I want to give some credit to your answer, Can I undelete my question? Can you post this answer, I will accept it?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Okay, thank you very much. I started getting downvotes so deleted my question actually. I would like to thank you for catching my question and answering here. Thanks.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, copied. You can delete now.

Answer (score 0):

Following will also work,

```
priority = %i(:green yellow red)

priority.inject({}) { |m, v| m[v] = hash[v]; m }
```